# Media queries for each browser

Tags: html, css

I want to resize my input field as per browser. can I write media query for each browser so separate width for input field on separate browser, like for mozilla it will have separate width on chrome and opera it will have separate width.

Comment: You might want to check http://browserhacks.com/

Answer (score 7):

[Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) are *media* queries, not *browser* queries. They are there to test certain properties of the viewport, device or display. There are no media features that let you test for a certain browser.

Comment: Excuse me sir, but you're wrong. 
A browser can be targeted with a media query ( see here : http://browserhacks.com/ )


For example, this media query is specific to FF+30 

   
    `@media all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: 3e1dpcm) {}`


Also, using "@supports" can be a way to target a specific browser, example : `@supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar) and (background-blend-mode:difference,normal) {}` will target FF>30

Comment: @LukyVj: The very name of the site should tell you that it's not actually a way of targeting a browser, but rather a hack, that happens to do work that way. It's kind of the same as CSS hacks in the early 2000s which over time stopped working, as browsers changed. The exhibited behaviour isn't a result of the specification, but rather of quirks in the implementation. They will cease to work eventually and are unsupported (e.g. if Mozilla inadvertently breaks this, they won't bend over backwards to make it work again).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this you should be able to find something on browserhacks.com which has a bunch of code samples to explain how to get a browser with css media queries so for IE you might do something like this.

`@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}`

This works because the only browser that those rules will apply on is Internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to have specific CSS for each browser,you may need to use browser specific hacks

Check the following article

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Browser specific hack is the solution for it!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want you use conditional CSS: 
http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced