# Media queries in different browsers

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using media queries in order to achieve responsive design. But I have found out that each browser behaves differently with it for example.

At resolution 480x856 chrome uses rules from `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` but Firefox uses rules from `@media screen and (max-width: 680px)` is there a way to achieve same result in all browsers?

Comment: could you post your code or any examples in jsfiddle?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480167/3365426

Comment: @stratovarius or Use SO snippets that keep the code nicely on this site for future developers with the same question - it's the document icon with the `<>` in it.

Comment: What's the pixel density of your device? It's possible that there's a difference in how each browser defines "pixel". http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html "*However, there are two tricky bits: the device-width media query and the <meta name="viewport" width="device-width"> tag. Both work with device pixels, and not with CSS pixels, because they report on the context of the web page, and not on its inner CSS workings.*"

Answer (score -1):

I find this post, maybe can help you.

"...It’s actually not a CSS or CSS interpretation problem at all–it’s the way Firefox does (or doesn’t) resize the viewport. Unlike Google Chrome, and most other browsers, Firefox allows it’s toolbars to affect viewport size. The only way to make the viewport resize below the width of your toolbars in Firefox is to disable them. You’ll need to go to View > Toolbars and uncheck each. Then try resizing and watch your media queries take effect."

https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/firefox-ignoring-max-width320px-media-query/

Comment: This is not a viable solution.. there's no way you can control how the browser looks and specifically their settings